# How to access to another view in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I think this kind of question is asked before but still I can't find the right answer for my case

I need to click in the nav header one option and then I want to load another view

Here is my controller

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
     function index (){
              $this->load->helper('url');
              $this->load->view('home');
            }
            public function contact() {

              $this->load->helper('url');
              $this->load->view('contcatus'); 
            }
    }
```

And my view home.php is

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('Pages/contact') ;?>">About us</a></li>

      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Education program<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Engineering program</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Business program</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'contact' ;?>">Contact us</a></li>
     </ul>

    <div class="navbar-header-right" id="signup">
     <a class="navbar-brand navbar-right" href="<?php echo base_url().'info' ;?>">Registration</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And the other view is contacact.php

```
<address>
  <strong>Student profile.eu.</strong><br>
  Skola Street 8 <br>
  Riga, Latvia <br>
  <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> (+) 371-28-949-227.<br>
  <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> (+) 371-26-291-600.
</address>
```

I need when I click on the navbar contact us in the first view to load the second one as you notice that I tried

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'contact' ;?>">Contact us</a></li>
```

but is not working also the sit_url(contact/pages) is not working  as well .

and my config is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'index.php';
```

and the route is:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages';
```

How could when I click on the `<li>contact us</li>` to load another view? . T.B.R

Comment: First off your base url is wrong. Should be `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

Comment: What is _T.B.R_?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a line at routes.php:

`$route['contact'] = 'Pages/contact';`

Algo, there's a better way to making URL's: `<?=site_url('contact')?>`, or using CodeIgniter's [anchor](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) function.

Furthermore, you can autoload the `url` helper at the autoload.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the base url

```
<li><?php echo anchor('Pages/contact','About us');?></li>
```

Using anchor automatically routes the address through the controller to the method